# Telerik Html5 report viewer client side parameters not being applied

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telerik-reporting

telerik reports ver Q2 2014 SP1 (8.1.14.804)

I Implemented an asp.net mvc 4 web api report server using the default ReportTypeResolver. Reports are designed using vs2010 report designer, so the report id is the "class, dll".

The report works just fine, but it is using the 'test' report parameters defined in the designer, not the ones being sent by the client. I can see the parameters being passed to the service in fiddler but they are not applied to the report.

The reportscontroller looks like this:

```
Public Class ReportsController

    Inherits ReportsControllerBase

    Protected Overrides Function CreateCache() As Interfaces.ICache
        Return CreateFileCache()
    End Function


    Protected Overrides Function CreateReportResolver() As IReportResolver
        Return New ReportTypeResolver
    End Function

End Class
```

The html5 widget:

```
$("#reportViewer1").telerik_ReportViewer({
serviceUrl: "http://server/api/reports",
templateUrl: "telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.1.14.804.html",
reportSource: {
    report: "Reports.ItemReport, Reports",
    parameters: {
        CultureID: "en",
        mydata: "some_data"
    }
}
```

});

I thought it should be 'automatic' but since it is not I suspect I need to add something to the server controller to somehow get the client parameter to the report.

Since I am using an older version the docs do not exactly match what I have, plus the docs are tantalizingly insufficient in many cases.

Now I am using reports that were designed for and worked in a silverlight app, not that the server side has any care about that, but in silverlight I passed the parameters by intercepting the ReportViewer1_RenderBegin event and getting the getReportParams object.

Q: how can I pass client side parameters to the report?

EDIT:

OK, I figured out that if I create a custom report resolver, serialize the the report object as xml, and then change the parameters they do get passed to the report...problem is I don't know how to get the client side values.

Here is a dirty test implementation:

```
Public Class CustomReportResolver

Implements IReportResolver

Public Function Resolve(reportId As String) As ReportSource Implements IReportResolver.Resolve

    Dim rpt As New Reports.ItemReport

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Using xmlWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb)
        Dim xmlSerializer As New Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer()
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, rpt)
    End Using

    Dim reportSource As New Telerik.Reporting.XmlReportSource()

    'down and dirty replace of ReportTitle parameter...
    reportSource.Xml = sb.ToString.Replace("<String>Report</String>", "<String>Foo-Bar</String>")

    Return reportSource
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I'm starting to think the custom resolver is not the place to do this, although it could be done there by some trick to append the params to the report id...since the client viewer has a params collection that MUST be the intended technique to use and I think it should be automatic so I  must have something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer:

I have concluded this is due to a misunderstanding on my part as to how report parameters work.  The report viewer is designed to display a parameter area where the user enters report parameters then hits refresh (if parameter auto-refresh is false). The parameters in the viewer widget setup will pre-populate the matching params in this area but if all params are either not visible or visible and have a default (designer provided) value the report will render initially with the default values.  I had all params not visible because I intend to have my own parameter settings which did two things, first it caused the report to render on initialization, second, it prevented display of the preview button.  therefore the report always rendered with the default values giving the illusion that it ignored the passed parameters.

Now since I intend to not use the built-in parameter area I set the report parameters in the resolver.  To do this I pass the report name followed by a url encoded list of params, then in the resolver I create a name-value collection and assign the values to the report parameters.

Now if I do not provide a designer value to a parameter the report shows an error about a missing parameter, so there is still some funny stuff going on, but my solution does resolve the problem in the way I wanted it resolved.

in the html:

```
$("#reportViewer1").telerik_ReportViewer({
serviceUrl: "https://server/api/reports",
templateUrl: "telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.1.14.804.html",
reportSource: {
    report: "ItemReport?sortBy=0&allDates=true&ItemList=0,1,2,3,7,10&ReportTitle=it works!",
    parameters: {
        CultureID: "en"
    }
}
```

});

then in the api:

```
Public Function Resolve(reportId As String) As ReportSource Implements IReportResolver.Resolve

    Dim theReport = reportId.Substring(0, reportId.IndexOf("?"))

    Dim rpt As Object = Nothing
    Select Case theReport
        Case "ItemReport"
            rpt = New Reports.ItemReport
    End Select

    Dim queryString As String = reportId.Substring(reportId.IndexOf("?") + 1)
    Dim params As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)

    For Each k As String In params
        rpt.ReportParameters(k).Value = params(k)
    Next

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Using xmlWriter As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb)
        Dim xmlSerializer As New Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer()
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, rpt)
    End Using

    Dim reportSource As New Telerik.Reporting.XmlReportSource()
    reportSource.Xml = sb.ToString

    Return reportSource

End Function
```